# Fixing W10 boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

ok I have issue. I install new hdd in laptop to install ubuntu on it and first hdd have w10 so I install ubuntu on 2. hdd and all good but thing is I need pull out that 2. hdd out and theres come issue I cant boot windows10, I can boot windows 10 only when 2. hdd is on and when I choose w10 loader. So how fix this as It is not option to reinstall windows 10 on 1 hdd. 
thanks

Comment: Have you Grub on hdd 2 ?   If so try moving it to hdd1, that should let you choose W10, when hdd2 is missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Windows `HDD` is `/dev/sda/` (you don't say, HDD.1 tells us nothing) run

`sudo install-grub /dev/sda`

then

`sudo os-prober`

finally

`sudo update-grub`

now you have a bootloader on both devices and can boot without the second HDD.